# Request entrando em loop infinito com HttpClient

Tags: angular

Estou fazendo um get para minha API local mas o método do serviço parece entrar em loop executando incontáveis requisições para o servidor

Tenho o `app.component.html` e dentro eu tenho o seguinte código

```
<div *ngIf="checkProfile()">
  <!-- <navbar *ngIf="false"></navbar> -->
</div>

<router-outlet *ngIf="!userSignedIn()"></router-outlet>
```

o método `checkProfile()` deveria retornar um boolean para entrar ou não na `div`.

aki está o método no `app.component.ts`:

```
  public checkProfile() {

    if (this.userSignedIn()) {
      this.profileService.getById(1)
        .subscribe(
          res => {
            console.log(res)
            return true;
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err)
            return true; 
          }
        )
    }

  }


  //retorna um boolean
  public userSignedIn(){
    return this.authService.userSignedIn();
  }
```

o serviço que esta sendo chamado e `profile.service.ts`:

```
  public getById(id: number): Observable<Profile> {
    let url = `${this.profileUrl}/${id}`;
    
    return this.http.get<Profile>(url)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleErrors),
        map(response => this.responseToProfile(response))
      )
  }

  private responseToProfile(response: any): Profile {
    return new Profile(
      response.data.attributes['user-id'],
      response.data.attributes.name,
      response.data.attributes.surname,
      response.data.attributes.birth,
      response.data.attributes.cpf,
      response.data.attributes.phone,
      response.data.id
    )
  }

  private handleErrors(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log("SALVANDO O ERRO EM UM ARQUIVO DE LOG - DETALHES DO ERRO => ", error);
    return throwError(error);
  }
```

e aki está o console da API mostrando as incontáveis requisições idênticas:

[image: Console-1]

[image: Console-2]

Comment: Não é bom usar funçoes assim no template. Tenta chamar seu endpoint primeiro e setando uma variavel no seu componente

Comment: Eu injetei OnInit, implementei na classe e criei o método ngOnInit, tbm criei a variável em `public profileExist: boolean = null;` e chamei no template. Dentro do onInit a request não fez infinitas requisições, o porem e que fiz isso usando um valor Id estaticos Id: '1', dentro do onInit meu CurrentUserData.id gerado pelo classe de Authenticação pós refresh de pagina nn chega, no ciclo de vida ela e gerado dpois, tentei usar ngAfterContentChecked mas aki dentro as infinitas requisiçoes tbm ocorrem